# Extend React.js store data structures with member functions?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, immutability

I'm using React.js and Typescript and in the React.js store I store Javascript objects. Sometimes they're sent by the server, so they're just objects, they have no member functions. But I want member functions, so that instead of this:

```
// Interface and "external" member function for an object in the store:
interface User {    
  id: UserId;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
  isModerator?: boolean;
  ...
}

function isStaff(user: User) {
  return user.isAdmin || user.isModerator;
}

if (isStaff(user)) {
  showPowerOffDataCenterButton();
}
```

I can do this:

```
if (user.isStaff()) {
  ...
```

Is there any React or Javascript features or Typescript syntactic-sugar magic that can add member functions to the React store data structures? Please note that the objects are sometimes sent from the server as JSON and parsed with `JSON.parse(..)`, so I don't think I can declare my own Javascript classes and add functions to their `.prototype` field (becasue I don't control the creation of the objects).

(I'm planning to use [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) later + some immutable-JS library, in case that matters)

Or if not possible, any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a class that contains that information instead of having them in separate functions.

```
interface UserInfo {
    id: string;
    isAdmin?: boolean;
    isModerator?: boolean;
}
class User {
    constructor(private user: UserInfo) { }

    public isStaff(): boolean {
        return this.user.isAdmin || this.user.isModerator;
    }
}

let user: User = new User({ id: "wqe" });
console.log(user.isStaff());
```

You can also make getters and setters for the properties, so you don't lose expresiveness.

```
class User {
    constructor(private user: UserInfo) { }

    public isStaff(): boolean {
        return this.user.isAdmin || this.user.isModerator;
    }

    public get isAdmin() {
        return this.user.isAdmin;
    }

    public set isAdmin(value) {
        this.user.isAdmin = value;
    }
}
```

You can then get or set isAdmin as you would on a normal object.

```
user.isAdmin = false;
```

You can also enforce that **isAdmin** can not be set by not making a setter for it. so the **User** class is immutable.

Comment: I like this approach. And hmm I'd like to avoid `new `. I could just make a wrapper for that, like `_user(userData).doWhatever(x,y,z)` instead of `new User(userData).doWhatever(x,y,z)`. Another similar approach could be to keep the functions I have now but prefix them with `user`, like `userDoWhatever(userData, x,y,z)`. Then intellisense would work after I've typed `user` so that "everyone" would be able to find the "member functions".

Comment: you could just make a function that calls new User, but it would be an unnecessary level of indirection. To me creating a new instance of the User class seems more clear if done with new User. :)

Comment: What I'll do is this: `user_isStaff(user)`, a bit like the C people do. — I think this is the simplest possible approach :-) and insellisense will work once I've typed `user_`.